# Monitor GPU performance on OSX

Tags: macos, performance, temperature, gpu

Is there an application or tool that can monitor GPU performance on OS X? Specifically I would like to see the current speed/utilization and temperature of the integrated NVIDIA chip.

For Windows, there is CPU-Z and MSI Afterburner. I cannot find anything for OS X, not even an NVidia control panel app.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Activity Monitor that comes with MacOS in Applications>Utilities

Choose Window>GPU History

or press ⌘4

[image: GPU monitoring Mac]

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: MacOS includes the in-built `powermetrics` command line tool which allows for access to varity of performance and power info. e.g. to obtain running GPU info every 5 seconds:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers gpu_power
```

To access all info (inluding temperatures for certain devices) run it without any arguments. Or to sample GPU usage for one iteration (`-n1` over say 200ms (`-i200`):

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers gpu_power -n1 -i200
```

The [Intel Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-power-gadget.html) also allows for monitoring of Intel GPUs, along with other measures of power usage for CPU, temperature, etc. It also has command line tools that provides for logging to a file.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm using [iStat Monitor](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), which is a really great app.

**GPU monitoring is also supported**. Here i found [YouTube Review](http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/fBfCFLrhwrA/maxresdefault.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBfCFLrhwrA&h=720&w=1280&tbnid=v0Di-mvABKAz2M%3a&zoom=1&docid=TjLEPVEqicVT4M&ei=FLE-U4LEHcSjtAbLuYDYDg&tbm=isch&iact=rc&dur=350&page=1&start=0&ndsp=47&ved=0CKYBEK0DMBk) (not related with me, have further searches for better/other reviews)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried iStat, and it was not informative when the Intel chip was used - no processor usage. Even for NVidia, there is only fps, memory and processor usage.

Comment: All the temperature monitors are put together in Sensors in iStat

Comment: I tried it with my 27" iMac with the NVidia GeForce GTX 780M and it shows the GPU processor usage as well as fps. Works great!