# top alternative for GPU usage and networking

Tags: macos, network, gpu, activity-monitor

I want to get all the info from Activity Monitor in the terminal (because I am executing these commands in macOS app). It also has to terminate - e.g. for `top` I can write:

`top -pid <somepid> -l3 -n30 > test ; tail -n42 ./test > ./test2 ; open ./test2`

and this would get 3 recordings and terminate.

So far, I managed to run `top` command and get most of the metrics. However, there are many that `top` doesn't provide, such as GPU and networking.

I am familiar with `systemstats` but this is not on a per-process basis. I can grep some parts of systemstats, but there is not guarantee that my process is going to be in the list of GPU usage section.

Need to support 10.14 Mojave and 10.15 Catalina

Any other commands that I can use, or maybe ways I can tweak systemstats to work for my case?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126484/119271

Answer (score 2):

- `netstat` : This command shows network status
- `iostat` : This command displays information about CPU usage, and I/O statistics
- `vm_stat` : This command virtual memory statistics

To my knowledge, there is no command to get GPU usage on macOS.

Comment: OK, I am familiar with some of them, *but* they don't satisfy my requirements. First, they aren't on a per-process basis. Second, I need something that terminates and gives the results.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in a GPU monitoring script on Mac M1 and M2. For `SAMPLE_MS` I recommend 5-20. Anything higher and it can impacts the system. I only execute this every few seconds to minimize slowing the GPU.

`SAMPLE_MS=5` and call every 6+ seconds and has virtually no impact on the system. I `tee` the output of my monitoring script into a CSV file so I can graph it.

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers gpu_power -i${SAMPLE_MS} -n1 | \
    grep "GPU active residency" | cut -w -f4 | sed -e "s/%//g"
```

Comment: It's rarely required to combine grep and sed in a pipe -> `sudo powermetrics --samplers gpu_power -i${SAMPLE_MS} -n1 | sed -En 's/GPU active residency: *([\.0-9]*)\%.*/\1/p'`